# I did the puzzle in the wrong order on the island

Tags: the-cave

I blew up the powder kegs and opened the mechanical door before I brought the boat into the cave.  Now, it appears that I am stuck and there is no other way to get the boat to the other side of the island.  Does anyone know if there is a fix for this without having to start the game over?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Opening the door shouldn't prevent you from getting the boat across.

Answer (score 2):

That's fine. As with the other approach, bring the boat through those same places.

You should realize that you can push the boat from behind so just push it into the now emptied area where the door switch is located. Water or not, the boat should fall so you can continue solving the rest of the island.

On some of my several playthroughs to get all achievements, I did it in this order. It's even done in this order [in this guide](http://guides.gamepressure.com/thecave/guide.asp?ID=18559).

There are no dead-end puzzles that I've encountered in this game and I've tried to find them. I've managed to come up with some cheap solutions thanks to time-traveller's teleportation, but never been stuck.